# High-pitched noise from boost converter. Need your help

Tags: noise, boost

I'm experiencing some high-pitched squealing noise from my boost converter, I'm getting some resonating frequency when I start increasing the load current.The inductor is a [47uH inductor](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/2200_series.pdf). The part number for the diode is MBRD640CTT4G.

This is my schematic:

[image: schematic] [1]

I checked the power line with the scope and this is the 12V line @ 100mA using AC Coupling:

[image: scope trace #1] [2]

As you can see, the ripple noise isn't so bad, I'm getting about 200mV peak to peak.

But when I run it at 500mA load this is what happens:

[image: scope trace #2] [3]

The ripple is horrible, I'm getting about 4V p-to-p.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Try putting the scope on the 12V source; it may be failing to deliver enough current. Otherwise, it looks like the regulator's control loop is going unstable, but I can't immediately see why this would be the case.

Comment: Forgot to mention, those measurements are taken at the Vin pin.

Comment: Dave, I am using a BK  Precision Bench power supply, and it has enough juice for this circuit. I'm capping it at 8A, so no problems there.

Comment: If you suspect that control loop goes unstable, try adding a small capacitor between Vout and FB.  Somewhere between 100pF and 10000pF.  BTW, the datasheet for LT1268 is only 4 pages.  No "Principles of Operation" chapter.  No "Application Info" chapter.  This is uncharacteristic of Linear Technology.

Comment: I fixed it. I will add my answer to my own question.

Comment: If you look closely, the datasheet refers you to [AN19](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Application%20Note/an19fc.pdf), which is a comprehensive manual (80 pages) for this whole family of parts. I've been perusing it, and there's a lot of information about compensation and also a phenomenon called "subharmonic oscillation". Well worth reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went into AN19 http://cds.linear.com/docs/Application%20Note/an19fc.pdf and it has a section for Frequency Compensation on pin VC. I simply increased the capacitance to 1uF and kept the resistor on 1K and I no longer have this problem. I am going to talk to Linear Tech to better fine tune this circuit and see if there is a more optimal value for that Capacitor (C112).

Comment: I was about to bring up that point next! :-)